# AD FS and DC on same Server

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, adfs

i have to connect AD with Azure AD but we have a 2008 r2 server and wwe don`t want to upgrade the server to 2012 r2. Is it possible to have the domain controller and the ADFS server on the same server. And is it also possible for the ADFS Proxy ? Are there any security issues when we do like i described it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for ADFS and ADFS Proxy, no it is not possible to install an ADFS and ADFS Proxy on the same server.  (Last time I researched this was 2013, it might have been changed but I highly doubt it)

However it is possible to [install ADFS on a DC](https://serverfault.com/questions/309402/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-install-adfs-on-the-ad-server-itself) especially because the ADFS server itself does not present significant load.
But you still need to properly distribute your Domain Controllers, meaning if you only have one server that serves as DC you might as well have none. (A bit exagurated but [it is a really bad idea](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0f00b67a-16c6-4c05-a7a7-95afa4658920/only-one-domain-controller-enough-disaster-preparedness))

What's stopping you from upgrading to 2012 R2? It's not like it's new and unproven anymore, you'll have to bite the bullet sooner or later and this is a perfectly valid reason why you should do it now.

Comment: The removal of the IIS dependency for AD FS on Windows Server 2012 R2 was done for many reasons. One reason why it was done was to make it easy to co-locate AD FS role on domain controllers. The idea is to make AD FS as easily available as AD is onpremise.